# How to pass IEnumerable<T> to View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, webgrid

Hello i'm newbie to MVC,
i want to display webgrid in view,I'm trying to display create and display in same page,i'm getting problem at the time of displaying data in webgrid,

This is my code:
Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Insert(Torder Model)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                ntity.Torders.Add(Model);
                ntity.SaveChanges();
                ModelState.Clear();
                TempData["notice"] = "Successfully registered";
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                TempData["Failure"] = ex;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["Failure"] = "Record Not Saved";
        }

        //var empoyees = Employee.GetList();

        IEnumerable<Torder> model1 = GetProducts();
        return View(model1);
    }
    public IEnumerable<Torder> GetProducts()
    {
        List<Torder> objStudent = new List<Torder>();
        ///*Create instance of entity model*/

        /*Getting data from database for user validation*/
        var _objuserdetail = (from data in ntity.Torders
                              select data);
        foreach (var item in _objuserdetail)
        {
            objStudent.Add(new Torder { Cid = item.Cid, Ccustomername = item.Ccustomername, Citem = item.Citem, Corderamount = (int)item.Corderamount});
        }
        return objStudent;
    }
```

Comment: What Problem? Any exception you are getting? Be Specific.

Comment: @saikrishnareddy, edit you question with the additional code (and delete your comment)

Comment: i want to display sql table data in view (in web grid using List),i need help there..

Comment: What is a "web grid"?

Comment: We can define WebGrid to display data on a web page using an HTML table element. It renders tabular data in a very simple manner

Comment: i'm thinking it is gridview like control in asp.net mvc.

Comment: Add your view code as well.

Comment: @model IEnumerable<MVCmyCrudApp.Models.Torder>
<div>
       @{
           var grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 5,
       selectionFieldName: "selectedRow",ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent");
       grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);} 
       }
   </div>

Comment: no error but not showing the control on view

Comment: is it any problem with using insert and display functionalities in same controller which is having [HttpPost] method..?

Comment: Don't ad code in comments, learn to _edit_ your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass your `IEnumerable<Torder>` like `List<Torder>` On page you can write `foreach loop` and create grid

```
--- Example:
public class Torder
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Insert(Torder Model)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                ntity.Torders.Add(Model);
                ntity.SaveChanges();
                ModelState.Clear();
                TempData["notice"] = "Successfully registered";
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                TempData["Failure"] = ex;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["Failure"] = "Record Not Saved";
        }

        //var empoyees = Employee.GetList();

        List<Torder> model1 = GetProducts();

        return View(model1);
    }
    public List<Torder> GetProducts()
    {
        List<Torder> objStudent = new List<Torder>();
        // your logic
        return objStudent;
    }

---------
Page:
-------------
//html code
@model  List<Torder>
@foreach(Torder order in Model)
{
// here you can build you grid(table) 
order.Name
order.Id
}
```

P.S In future I recommend write "clean" `UI` without `Razor` (Try learn `Angular` - it's really very good `framework`) –

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from code in comments, but you might just be missing the `@grid.GetHtml()`
The block you've shown defines the grid, but now you need to emit the HTML so something shows on the page.  Put this after your @{} block right before the closing div tag.